# MailChimp subscribe popup not displaying but displaying after admin login

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I am using MailChimp subscribe popup on my Wordpress website. I am getting one issue. I added the below code on my website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us5.list-manage.com","uuid":"e47ee5fe210b931aa5a748840","lid":"2b074a0a8b","uniqueMethods":true}) })</script>
```

I am not getting the popup on my website but if I log in to the WordPress and refresh the page then I am getting the popup.
I checked in the console I am getting the error

> TypeError: window.dojoRequire is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a load order issue. Try moving those lines to the footer - before the body close tag.